# Why do some bad questions not have negative votes?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting, bad-questions

Take a look at this question:

[Import .bk file into oracle db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74158624/import-bk-file-into-oracle-db)

It is terrible with the user having done no research either. But yet it did not get any downvotes, and I am wondering why.

Is it because their question was closed, so people did notice that the question was bad?

Comment: What is the point to bring that question for discussion here?

Comment: Is importing very large files into database systems a new trend? What is the name of the university course? Or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: You invoked the [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect)!

Comment: @peter not sure what you mean by  "Is importing very large files into database systems a new trend? What is the name of the university course? Or is it just a coincidence?"

Comment: @Ruben I am trying to understand what make a person earn negative points on his/her post

Comment: In order to better help you, we need more context, but before editing your post, please spend some time reading the related help articles and the [meta-tag:faq].

Comment: @Rubén - The point of bringing it here is to do a huge whataboutism. Given Sami's recent posts on meta (many of which were nonconstructive and deleted), they likely wish to bemoan their question ban as unfair, because "well, this question that wasn't curated exists".

Answer (score 33):

#### Because there are a lot of questions, and some don't get looked at much

When I got to this, four hours after you asked this and caused a bunch of people from meta to view the question, it *still* had only 49 views.

We get over 6000 questions on an average day (as determined by looking at the last 30 days).  We don't have enough people looking at all of them to ensure they're all scored in relation to their quality.  We'd need 150 people casting all their votes in a day, entirely on questions, to ensure that those questions get even *one* vote each.

People vote on what they see.  If people don't see a bad question, it might not get downvoted.  But then, it probably won't get answered either.

Answer (score 16):

Where to begin...

> it is terrible with the user having done no research also but yet it did not get any negative points , wondering why .

It's objectively unclear, but if one has to import large files into their Oracle database, it would be valuable.

But more to the point, just because someone hasn't done research on something doesn't automatically make their question a bad one. We can't have this awkward double standard of both having done a lot of research into the problem and then being roasted for asking about an aspect of it.

> His question was closed so people did notice that question was bad .

The question was closed because it was unclear. The OP mentioned commands, but they didn't include them, so it makes sense that, instead of us guessing, that we close the question and give the OP time to fill in what commands they ran and what errors they saw.